# How to empty a Mongoose map?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to make an API route where you can clear the data in a map field, but somehow that won't work.
The field is declared in this way:

```
....
sessieData: {
  type: Map,
  required: false,
  default: {},
  validate: {
    validator: function (v) {
      if (typeof v !== 'object') {
        return false;
      }
    },
    message: 'You must provide a valid map object'
  }
}
....
```

I want the delete action to be that the map is cleared of data, but not set to null. However, when I assign an empty map value - {} - to the field, the map retains the data that is in the field.

I also tried going over the keys of the current map, and delete all the keys one by one. But that also does not work (nor produce an error of any kind).

How do you clear a Map field?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the best solution is to assign null to the field, and then assign an empty object {} to it. Still a mystery why just assigning the empty object won't work, but the problem is solved for me in this way.